# Trying to use multiple 1D Arrays while also Reading a File in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

I'm a new java programmer and I'm currently starting to learn how to read files. I am working on an activity where I need to read numbers from a text file into integer arrays in a separate method and then add values from each of the three arrays in the main method.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileToArrays{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] b = new int [7];
        int[] l = new int [7];
        int[] d = new int [7];
        readFile(b, l, d);

        System.out.println("Sum of First Numbers: "+(b[0]+l[0]+d[0]));
        System.out.println("Sum of Second Numbers: "+(b[1]+l[1]+d[1]));
        System.out.println("Sum of Third Numbers: "+(b[2]+l[2]+d[2]));
        System.out.println("Sum of Fourth Numbers: "+(b[3]+l[3]+d[3]));
        System.out.println("Sum of Fifth Numbers: "+(b[4]+l[4]+d[4]));
        System.out.println("Sum of Sixth Numbers: "+(b[5]+l[5]+d[5]));
        System.out.println("Sum of Seventh Numbers: "+(b[6]+l[6]+d[6]));
        System.out.println("");
    }

    static void readFile(int[] b, int[] l, int[] d){
        try{
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));
            int day = 0;
            while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scnr.nextLine();
                String [] words = line.split(" ");
                b[day]  = Integer.parseInt(words [0]);
                l[day]  = Integer.parseInt(words [1]);
                d[day]  = Integer.parseInt(words [2]);
                day++;
            }
            scnr.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Unable To Find File");
        }
    }
}
```

And the text file ("Input.txt") of numbers that I'm reading into arrays is formatted as:

```
800  1000 800
450  845  1200
1800 250  400
0    1500 1800
600  500  1000
700  1400 1700
675  400  900
```

The program compiles without error, but when I tried running it every value in the three arrays appear as 0.

I feel like the issue could either be something trivial like an error in my parameters and formatting, or I could have messed up the way I read the file into arrays.

Nevertheless any insight on where I messed up or advice on how to approach similar tasks in the future would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: it is working for me, the problem might be the location of your input file, give the absolute path. like "C:/Users/input.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Give absolute path for input file(like "C:/Users/input.txt"), it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Jake,
 The code looks good but is not working fine for the provided file/data. If you look carefully there are more than one space between the numbers.
 You are splinting the line on each space `String [] words = line.split(" ")` that is giving you an array bigger than you are expecting.

A better approach for this kind of "task" is to use `Scanner.next()`, that will ignore all blank spaces. [More info on Scanner here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Try to replace your code with this:

```
        while(scnr.hasNext()){
            b[day]  = scnr.nextInt();
            l[day]  = scnr.nextInt();
            d[day]  = scnr.nextInt();
            day++;
        }
```